# Consistently tracking scroll with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the following piece of code:

```
(function($){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();

        if (scroll_top > 50 && scroll_top < 100) {
            console.log(scroll_top);
        }
    });
})(jQuery)
```

Viewing the console shows me a range of numbers between 50 & 100 whilst I scroll up and down, as expected.

However, I need a way to log each number between 50 & 100 as I've scrolled. So that if I stop at 55 it would log 51, 52, 53, 54, 55.

I understand that this is because browsers run javascript and render the page at different speeds but is it at all possible?

Comment: No this is not possible for the reason you mention; browsers all run JS events at different speeds depending on the hardware being used. You cannot get each pixel scrolled as it happens as the event is only raised on each redraw of the UI, however if you keep track of what the value was on the previous event and what it is now, you can extrapolate the direction and how many pixels have been scrolled.

Comment: "I understand that this is because browsers run javascript and render the page at different speeds": no, it's mostly because when you turn the mousewheel it happens in intervals, no continuously.

Comment: If you want to log all numbers just use a for loop.

Comment: @Prinzhorn not true, if you move the mousewheel the browser still scrolls through each pixel of that movement. It's down to the update speed of the UI whether all of the pixels scrolled are detected, or if there is jumps (this is of course you have smooth scrolling turned on, which most OSs do by default these days)

Comment: @Prinzhorn Unfortunately, a loop wouldn't work in this case. This is a very simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
var scroll_pos_at_mousedown;
var aa = function(){

    $(window).on('scroll mouseup mousedown', function(e){
        var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();


        if(e.type == 'mousedown') {

            var scroll_top1 = $(document).scrollTop();
            if(scroll_top1 <= 50) {
                scroll_pos_at_mousedown = 50;
            } else if(scroll_top1 > 50 || scroll_top1 <= 500) {
                scroll_pos_at_mousedown = scroll_top1;
            } else {
                scroll_pos_at_mousedown = 500;
            }
            console.log("scroll_top is "+scroll_top1);
        }

        console.log("current_scroll_top is " + scroll_pos_at_mousedown);


        if (scroll_top > 50 && scroll_top < 500) {
            if(e.type == "mouseup") {
                var scroll_pos_at_mouseup = $(document).scrollTop();
                console.log('scroll_pos_at_mouseup is '+scroll_pos_at_mouseup);
                if(scroll_pos_at_mousedown<=500) {
                    for(i=scroll_pos_at_mousedown;i<=scroll_pos_at_mouseup;i++)
                        console.log(i);
                }else {
                    for(i=scroll_pos_at_mouseup;i<=500;i++)
                        console.log(i);
                }
            }


        }
    });
};aa();
```

I have written this function keeping event mousedown and mouseup in mind. You can add keyup and keydown event as well and add it for up and down arrow keyCode. Hope this helps :)